# Can't use auto-completion in gnome-builder for Python -- jedi plugin not found

Tags: gnome, python, plugins, gnome-builder

I am using the `gnome-builder` to do some development work, and I am needing to do some work with Python so it would be really helpful if the auto-completion tool actually worked, but every time I start `gnome-builder` I get the following message in Terminal:

```
jedi not found, python auto-completion not possible.
```

Even though `jedi` is listed as one of the installed `gnome-builder` plugins, so what is the problem and how can I get `jedi` to work or be detected?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: ...need to visit Yoda fist.

Comment: OK. I think I should probably edit the title for Panda. He was tired and forgot to fix it before he posted. Then his internet was too slow to fix it so he went to bed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gnome-builder plugin system uses Python 3, so make sure `Jedi` is installed for that Python version.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-jedi
```

You can confirm installation is successful by typing the following in the terminal:

```
python3 -c "import jedi; print(jedi.__file__)"
```